# Bootstrap Cards, show 2 of them in a row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

[image]

This is how it looks when I have some cards beneath each other by using:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        stuff
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">stuff</div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

What did I miss out on CSS in order for them to not look this weird, but adapt?
I want to have it aligned like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

```css
.cards-container {
  column-count: 2;
}

.cards-container div {
   background: floralwhite;
   height: 50px;
   margin: 10px 0;

   // to avoid column breaks
   -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
   page-break-inside: avoid;
   break-inside: avoid;
}

.cards-container div:first-child {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards-container">
<div class="col-md-6">
    stuff
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">stuff</div>
<div class="col-md-6">stuff</div>
<div class="col-md-6">stuff</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abhaysnaik22/x28Lm7jn/1/)

HTML Structure:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col">
        stuff
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col col1">stuff</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col col1">stuff</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">stuff</div>
</div>
```

```
.row > div {
    background: lightgrey;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

.col{
    height:100px;
}

.col.col1{
    height:50px;
}
```

PS: You can replace 'xs' with 'md' for desktop.